# Run JavaScript code SublimeText

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I tried to run javascript code from SUBLIME TEXT 3 but no works.
I tried by setting the build system, once i open it shows me:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "make"
}
```

i change it by:

```
{
  "shell_cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

but the package no appear in build system. 
How can i solve this problem?

I have already installed NodeJS in my pc.

Comment: @luke_aus problem is that the package that i created no appears on the build system.

Comment: did you save it? Its a new file that you are creating, so you need to save it. Save it as 'Javascript' cause that sounds like a sensible description

Comment: yes, i saved it into the sublime package. but as i mentioned before, no appear in build system pallete.

Comment: I had the wrong Instructions... should be: did you change the build system to use javascript? That needs to be done in addition to making the build system. Go to Tools --> Build System --> Javascript (or whatever you called the file you saved the build system in)

Comment: yes i did. i went directly to change the build system by the new created one, but problem is that the package that i try to create no appears ..

Comment: did you save it? If so, to where? Find out where this file is

Comment: yes i saved it, is in the SublimeText's package.. but no appear in the build system pallete..

Comment: where is the file saved to - what path?

Answer (score 3):

When I tried it before I made a new build system and pasted this

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js",
}
```

Comment: `C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe` instead and you need to add `file_patterns` to it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `shell_cmd` mentioned in the *official* [Build Systems](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) documentation and it doesn't work for in Sublime Text (Build 3119).

**Update**: If I'm interpreting error message in the console correctly,  `shell_cmd` does not accept any arguments, hence you cannot pass `$file`!

Anyway, the following works just fine for me:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js",
  "windows" : {
     "shell": true
  }
}
```

Make sure you save the as `whatever.sublime-build` in `Packages/User`. That's the default location when you're using the dialog to create a new build system (*Tools > Build System > New Build System*).

Also, I see no reason to put the full path to `node`, since the Node.js installer adds it to your [PATH environmental variable](https://superuser.com/a/284351/195953). If you want use an absolute path, you should probably follow Windows conventions and use back-slashes – just make sure they're escaped, which is JSON convention (e.g. `C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe`).

Comment: No works.. i don't know why i have tried a lot of options but build system no add any of all build system that i have tried to add....

Comment: I know this is old but for anyone else that struggles with it, you need to save your file first for it to be passed to node executable :)

Answer (score 0):

### **1. For linux based os.**

first install nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

then create a build system under tools panel on sublime text, save it as **javascript.sublime-build** or **anyword.sublime-build**

then paste this code and save,

```
{
    "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

make sure that the saving directory is:

```
/home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/
```

then on build systems select which build system you want. in this case select javascript.

example.
create a new file like index.js and add this code.

```
var add = function(x,y){
    return x+y;
}

console.log(add(2,3));
```

then press **ctl+B** key. A console terminal opens at the bottomm of the page.

```
5
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For Windows Users

first you have to install nodeJS. If it is already installed  open command prompt and type `where node` it will show the directory where it is installed, it must be here -

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

copy this path and go to environment variables Select PATH then EDIT then NEW and then PASTE the copied address and then click OK

Now open sublime text goto TOOLS > BUILD SYSTEM >NEW BUILD SYSTEM 
   Paste the code given below

```
{
  "shell_cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

Save it with name `JavaScript.sublime-build` in location -

```
C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

NOTE that here "Acer" is username. 
Now restart Sublime text and you will able to see a new build system named as JavaScript,

Answer (score 0):

No answer has `file_patterns` in it which is required, well at least I had trouble getting it to work without it.

```
{
  "selector": "source.js",
  "file_patterns": ["*js"],
  "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
}
```

More info on Sublime Texts' page:

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html